# Проброс исключения наверх в асинхронном коде

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность

У меня ASP.NET Core приложение. Мне нужно реализовать отправку почты. Есть простой EmailService с одним async методом, в нем происходит примерно следующее

```cs
await client.ConnectAsync(smtpOptions.Server, smtpOptions.Port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
await client.AuthenticateAsync(smtpOptions.Login, smtpOptions.Password);
await client.SendAsync(message);
await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
```

И дальше в контролере я использую этот сервис. Но я хочу сделать обработку ошибок. Каждый из методов ConnectAsync, SendAsync и.т.д может кинуть эксепшн(DisconnectAsync судя по доке кидает эксепшн только при неправильном использовании) и там разные типы эксепшнов. Но в любом из этих случаев(или не подключился или аутентификация не пройдена или все было нормально, но письмо не отправилось) результат один - почта не отправилась. Потому я хочу обернуть это в try catch, но наверх пробросить какое-то одно исключение, которое будет означать что операция не выполнилась успешно, чтобы в контроллере ловить единственный тип эксепшна. Правильно ли это и какой тип эксепшна кидать наверх из стандартных ? Вот так примерно хочу сделать.

```cs
// внутри метода Send в сервисе EmailService
try
{
    await client.ConnectAsync(smtpOptions.Server, smtpOptions.Port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    await client.AuthenticateAsync(smtpOptions.Login, smtpOptions.Password);
    await client.SendAsync(message);
    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
}
catch (Exception) {
    throw new OperationWasNotDone();
}

// а в контролере уже
try
{
    await emailService.SendAsync(...);
}
catch (SomeExceptionType)
{
    return SomeErrorCode();
}
```

Comment: Если у вас нет конечной цели обрабатывать каждый отдельный вид исключения, вы можете просто ловить общий `Exception`. Сам `catch` с родительским классом ловит исключения дочерних классов и все исключения наследуются от `Exception`.

Comment: Т.е выходит можно в сервисе не обрабатывать ? Пускай само идет наверх, а там ловить все эксепшны ? Хм, это мысль

Comment: Да, в вашем случае достаточно только в контролере один раз поймать. Иногда удобно прокидывать выше уже полученное исключение, если сервис хочет сделать какие-то еще действия перед этим. Исключение уйдет выше с тем же типом и можно поймать еще где-то: `catch (Exception e) { \*предварительные действия и кидаем дальше*\; throw e; }`

Comment: @AlexKrass спасибо, так и сделаю.

Comment: Но можно, конечно, сделать и свой тип исключения и кидать наверх его. Случаи разные бывают. Иногда удобно так, иногда эдак. Но в любом случае если вы хотите вместо нескольких разных исключений кидать какое-то одно, то лучше сделать своё исключение. Ну и вообще если нет исключения, чётко подходящего под ваши задачи, лучше делать своё исключение. Это не сложно, но гораздо понятнее потом по логам что собственно происходит.